# Linear algebra in a programming project (Preferably C)

Tags: linear-algebra, programming

I would like to merge both so I can improve my understanding and test my knowledge. I have been looking for ideas but I found nothing but *strange* research papers. Of course I am not looking for something close to regression models or linear programming as I do not have the required knowledge yet; rather to apply some part of the standard LA curricula in an introductory undergraduate course.

Comment: Try asking it in the programming branch of Stack Exchange.